# How to create a fullscreen size popup in Windows phone

Tags: popup, windows-phone

Fullscreen I mean the popup usercontrol covers the whole cellphone screen, maximize. can this be done?

thx!

Comment: is this really that difficult? maximize popup suit the screen size of different cellphone...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the current width and height by Content.ActualHeight/Width  property
here's a code snippet

```
    public void showPopUp()
    {
        //get heigth and width
        double height=Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight;
        double width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth;


      //child content
       StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
       stk.Height = height; //set height
       stk.Width = width; //set width
       stk.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
       TextBlock txtblock = new TextBlock() { FontSize=40, Text="HELLO WORLD", TextWrapping=TextWrapping.Wrap};
       stk.Children.Add(txtblock);


        Popup _popup = new Popup();

        _popup.Child = stk; //set child content

        this.LayoutRoot.Children.Add(_popup);
        _popup.IsOpen = true;

    }
```

and then you get this result ;)
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the post, it is wonderful. And it's been a while since... :-p

Answer (score 1):

For Windows Phone 8.1 you can get the current Application width and height by Window.Current.Bounds

```
double height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
double width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
```