# Show image in Full screen

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, fullscreen

I am working on `Windows Phone 8 app` and  have a Image view like this in XAML:

```
<Image Name="Image"
       Grid.Row="0"
       Visibility="Collapsed"
       Width="Auto"
       Height="Auto"
       Tap="Image_tap"
       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
       VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
```

Now i have this event called `Tap="Image_tap"`, when i tap on the image i want to show the same image in full screen without any bar on top and bottom, how to acheive this ?

Comment: Maybe you can Navigate to special FullScreen.xaml only with your image passed in context? Or have two grids, one with image and second with Ui, then you can change their visibility.

Comment: @Romasz can you please show me some example ?

Comment: Whait a while. Do you know how to pass context while Navigating?

Comment: @Romasz Ok, i will wait, No i am new to Windows phone 8 app development so no idea , but i have got this link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19173205/how-to-create-a-fullscreen-size-popup-in-windows-phone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bottom bar is `ApplicationBar` and top bar is `SystemTray`. If you create a new page without the `ApplicationBar` and with `SystemTray.IsVisible` to false, you have a fullscreen page. Now, instead of having a `Grid` at the root, place just one `Image` and you can use that page as a fullscreen viewer.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="SimpleApp.FullScreenPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

    <Image Name="myImage" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
         Stretch="Uniform"/>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

In MainPage where you tap image:

```
private void myImg_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
{
   string context = ((sender as Image).Source as BitmapImage).UriSource.ToString();
   NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri(String.Concat("/Page1.xaml?context=", context), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
}
```

In Fullscreenpage:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   string context = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["context"];
   myImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(context, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
   base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

Comment: If you can please show me how the XAML page like like ?

Comment: @ToniPetrina +1, I think there is no need to pass two same answers ;) - I've added a little.

Comment: Guys,i get this BitmapImage could not be found... which package i need to add ?

Comment: Hit Ctrl+. to add proper namespace

Comment: @Goofy using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

Comment: @Romasz got it, i have added everything now, but the app is crashing but how to see errors, i am not able to see what the error, sorry if i am asking silly question

Comment: @Goofy where it crashes, are running in debug mode, what do you mean that you can't see an error?

Comment: @Romasz i am not running the ap in debug mode, when i click on the image its crashing and it points to Debugger.break() in the App.xaml.cs page that it

Comment: @Goofy Then move your mouse pointer (when it had crashed) on small letter 'e' and check its content.

Comment: @Romasz i solved it, excellent this is what i was looking for, i have accepted the answer, i have few issue more can you help me out please

Comment: @Goofy I'm glad that we have helped. Unfortunately I don't have time because my break at work is nearly ending. Ask question then maybe someone else would have time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47666/discussion-between-goofy-and-romasz)

Comment: @Romasz can you please join

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach, without passing the image details between pages, is to display a Popup:

```
private void HandleTapImage(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
{
    var myPopup = new Popup
    {
        Child = new Image
        {
            Source = ((Image) sender).Source,
            Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill,
            Height = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualHeight,
            Width = Application.Current.Host.Content.ActualWidth
        }
    };
    myPopup.IsOpen = true; 
}
```

(Select Strech value best suited for your needs).
With this approach however you have to manually hide ApplicationBar and SystemTray, if present, in the `HandleTapImage` method. You also have to take care of hiding the Popup and showing the bars again.

Comment: i get this Pop could not be found? what is assembly reference name ?

Comment: +1 nice solution. I've added only parentheses and information about hiding Page Content if needed.

Comment: `System.Windows.Controls.Primitives`

Comment: I don't have time to try this method, but what happens if user presses the Back key?

Comment: @ToniPetrina This method isn't full. Back button must be handeled to close Popup. This example also lacks event when Popup is closing where you should change visibility of elements.

Comment: Aaaah, but then it is a much longer and complex solution.

Comment: @Romasz the idea of a popup is that you don't care about the content, because Popup will cover it. You only switch IsOpen true or false. So you don't have to hide Content, you don't have to show the Page again once you've hidden the Popup.

Comment: @lisp I do not agree - why do you expect the image to cover whole Page? For example if it is squere? And you removed parentheses, I do not know if it will work without them.

Comment: @ToniPetrina there might be a decision, that BackKeyPress hiding the fullscreen is not necessary (though I highly doubt that). There might be no SystemTray or AppBar to hide in the original Page, which would further simplify the case. In terms of amount of code, my solution might be shorter, might be longer, depending on scenario. After seeing your solution - which I would use - I suggested only an alternative. Perhaps for Goofy it would be a simpler solution, given his level of WP-development experience.

Comment: @Romasz yes, it's correct without the parentheses. please don't edit when you're not sure. also note that I used the Stretch property. There are a couple of them that guarantee covering the whole Page, UniformToFill is one of them.

Comment: @lisp With parentheses you are right. As for streching - It's your answer, I won't quarrel and touch your answer, as you wish. But I still think UniformToFill is a bad choice. Never the less I still think it's a nice answer. Don't take it personal and good luck.