# How to show images to fullscreen in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, fancybox

How to expand image to fullscreen, after the user clicked on it thumbnail? Which XAML element I should use? And how to close it back, when user clicked this fullscreen image? I try to create the mechanism that is similar to fancybox on jQuery, but on C#/XAML for Windows Phone 8.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried Popup control.?
check this link for more info about popup:

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/How_to_use_Pop-Ups_in_Windows_Phone

Comment: [Very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21829125/show-image-in-full-screen)